# java.io.IOException: org/at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:326)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When try to access data from excel2010 got error.the code is...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("D:\\Java Pgms\\Book1.xlsx");
    Workbook wk=  WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
    Sheet s=wk.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Row r= s.getRow(1);
    Cell c=r.getCell(0);
    String t=c.getStringCellValue();
    System.out.println(t);  
}
```

the error message is

```
java.io.IOException: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
atorg.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:326)
   at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createXSSFWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:296)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:214)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:180)
        at demoPack.Excell.main(Excell.java:21)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/ZipFile
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:298)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:129)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(WorkbookFactory.java:314)
        ... 4 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
```

Comment: don't forget to read the stacktrace: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile at

Comment: How is the project configured, are the POI libraries and dependencies on your classpath?

Are you using Maven, Gradle or another dependency management tool?

Answer (score 1):

you missed the *Apache common-compress* dependency. regarding  which build automation tool you are using, you can include it as:

## Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>
```

## Gradle/Grails:

```
compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.14'
```

## Jar File:

if you need the jar you can download it from [Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress/1.14)

---

> **More Info:**
>
> [Apache Commons Dependency Information](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/dependency-info.html)

Comment: I am using Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0).and already  I have included the necessary jar files

Comment: Thank u .I got the result.

Comment: what was the issue ?